# How do I browse the tor stackexchange from tor?

Tags: cloudflare, captcha

Since this has not been directly asked yet it seems, I thought we might as well address the elephant in the room.

Cloudflare prevents access to the CSS, images and javascript of the stackexchange sites unless a cloudflare captcha is entered to be able to access the resources hoted on cdn.sstatic.net.

How do we work with that ? Should we get a stackexchange admin involved so maybe they at least address the fact that static content is hosted elsewhere, with cloudflare protection ?

Fun fact: to ask this question I had to login. Loging in seems javascript based, so I had to get *.sstatic.net to bypass the tor socks proxy.

Comment: Funny thing. I'm using Tor right now, and I can get in fine. If you go to _The "S!" in the top left corner > Options > Whitelist_ you can add sites that can run scripts. I would add _https://tor.stackexchange.com_.

Comment: I would *not* recommend using the whitelist, as an attacker can fingerprint you based on what sites you have whitelisted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tor to access this stack exchange, but you will likely trip their "defenses" and have to complete captchas, human verifications, and then your post might get flagged as spam so you can't even submit it.

While that's a heaping load of irony, none of that is an insurmountable set of obstacles to posting here using tor or the tbb.

Once you get in and login, you can do all the tasks that you want to and can normally do.  In fact, you can browse without logging in, same as any other stack exchange.

I asked a similar question here:

[Stack Exchange “security” measures get tripped when using Tor and TBB](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7262/stack-exchange-security-measures-get-tripped-when-using-tor-and-tbb)